# How to count number of matches using page object?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

My application has a list and it's size changes very regularly. So I need to get the li count before starting the test cases. So this is how I used to get the count

```
b.lis(:xpath => "//ul[@id='global_nav']/li[contains(@id, 'nav-')]").count
```

Now I need to achieve this in page object way. I declared the list in my page file as below.

```
list_item(:global_nav_count, :xpath => "//ul[@id='global_nav']/li[contains(@id, 'nav-')]")
```

If I try to get count as below

```
page.global_nav_count_element.count
```

It returns method not found error. Can any one suggest any solution to achieve this in page object way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list_item` accessor is similar to Watir's `li` method in that it returns the first matching element. If you want a collection of elements, you need to tell the page object.

The accessor for a collection of `li` elements is `list_items` (note the plural):

```
list_items(:global_nav_count, :xpath => "//ul[@id='global_nav']/li[contains(@id, 'nav-')]")
```

The method created to access the collection is also pluralized:

```
page.global_nav_count_elements.count
```

Comment: Working as expected ! Thanks